# Amazon Transcribe Streaming Service

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I am new to Amazon Transcribe but I was not able to find any tutorials. Can anyone explain how to use Amazon Transcribe Streaming Service in C#.net?

Comment: Please [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) , and be sure to read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). try to give a detailed information about your question. Add your code , what issue your facing? , where your blocking? , what you tried so far? like the way you have to ask your question.

Comment: You can have a look at my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/66905418/6443084 Hope it helps!

Comment: Please have a look at my own answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/66905418/6443084 Hope it helps!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that you would use the [StartStreamTranscription - Amazon Transcribe](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/transcribe/latest/dg/API_streaming_StartStreamTranscription.html) API call.

Alas, as of writing this, it does not appear that this API call is available in the [AmazonTranscribeServiceClient Class | AWS SDK for .NET V3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/TranscribeService/TTranscribeServiceClient.html).

It might be a matter of waiting until the AWS SDK for .NET is updated. (It is not in the Python boto SDK either.)